# I need to ask the user to enter a quote. Split the quote into individual words by the spaces. Display each word on a new line

Tags: python

```
quote=input("Enter a quote ")
split=quote.split(quote)
for count in range(0,(split)+1):
    print(split)
```

I've tried to do this but gave me the error:
    for count in range(0,(split)+1):
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Comment: `.split` returns a string. `range(0,(split)+1)` would raise error.

Comment: Split returns a list (not string). To fix your code: you should use `len(split)`, no `+1`, then print `split[count]`. But better solution is to use this: `for word in split: print(word)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving the error because your `split` variable is a list and you are adding `+ 1` (which is an integer) to the list which you cannot do in Python, hence a `TypeError` is thrown because the two types are not compatible with the `+` operator and Python doesn't know what to do.

## Fixing the error

There are a few issues with the code that lead to that error being thrown and some minor logical issues:

- You need to make sure you are splitting the string by spaces, not by the string itself.
- You also need to get the length of the list of words in the string in your for loop.
- In the loop you need to make sure you are outputting each word, not the whole list

See the code below for more details:

```py
quote=input("Enter a quote ")

# Make sure to split by " " character
split=quote.split(" ")

# Make sure to get the length of the list of words in the split variable
for count in range(0, len(split)):
    # Print each word, not the whole array
    print(split[count])
```

Hope that helps ;)